# VirtualBox: Ubuntu Host and Ubuntu Guest. Where is my shared folder in the Guest?

Tags: virtualbox, directory

I am running VirtualBox OSE in an Ubuntu Lucid host.
The Guest system is also Ubuntu Lucid.

I've set up a Host directory to share with the Guest via VirutulBox's `Shared Folders`.
This directory is owned by the same user who is running the VM.
The permissions on the directory are: drwxrwxrw

I've installed `virtualbox-guest-additions`(via Synaptic)

I can't find the shared diretory on the Guest.

I've looked high and low, in /media and /mnt... nothing!

I managed to share the same directory with a Windows Guest, but I am familiar with Windows...

Am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you just need to mount the directory manually. To do that, use `mount -t vboxsf SHARENAME /path/to/where/to/mount`.

SHARENAME depends on your shared folder, it is the name you entered into VirtualBox Shared Folders dialog.

`/path/to/where/to/mount` should ideally be inside your user directory (inside VBox). In my case, I use `/home/evgeny-vbox/Documents`.

**EDIT**: if you want it to be mounted at boot-time too, add this to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
SHARENAME /path/to/where/to/mount vboxsf defaults 0 0
```

Comment: On the Guest, I tried: ubuntu@Lucid:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf zap /home/ubuntuzap... I got this error: /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device ..... /sbin/mount.vboxsf shows the Link Target as: /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf

Comment: How did you install the Guest Additions? Package that you installed provides the ISO, not the additions themselves. Follow this guide: http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/ . You might need to use `cd /media/VBOX*`

Comment: Initially I used the .ISO, and then, when that didn't seem to work, I installed the addons via Synaptic.... I'll start afresh, with an new VM, and follow the guide you've posted... and try again.  Thanks...

Comment: IIRC the sharename can be chosen in the dialog box of share creation (there is also a command line tool in the host), so it is not necessarily the last name in the path.

Comment: Good point, I stand corrected (and edited)

Comment: Bingo! got it! Evgeny, you deserve the "Hero Of The Day" award. Thanks... I think the problem was that in the Terminal, I ran 'autorun.sh', instead of 'VBoxLinuxAdditions-x86.run'.. ..(and of course, I did need your mount command).

Comment: I'm getting an "access denied" after mounting the shared folder both in /media/sharedfolder or in /home/username/sharedfolder

Comment: Solved: sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 driveshared /home/rho/driveshared/